# Want to build a widget which gives price history on Drupal 7

Tags: commerce, charts

We have our site built on Drupal 7. We want to make a widget which gives price history chart.

I found a module named Commerce Price History. 
Can this module be used with Drupal 7 or it can be used only with Drupal 
commerce.

Is there any other Drupal Module which can achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across a module called [Track Field Changes](https://drupal.org/project/track_field_changes) which may be ideal for you needs.

I found the documentation a bit lacking however but to get it to work I:

1. Install module
2. Visit /admin/config/system/track_field_changes and select your product node type
3. Save the configuration and then product will appear as a menu item in the left menu. Click it.
4. Select the price field and again save the configuration.
5. Create a new view that shows content of the type of your products.
6. Add the field called "Field Tracker: Value After (Value After)"

This will then show a log of all of your price changes. To then turn this into a graph check out the [Views Charts](https://drupal.org/project/views_charts) module.

Comment: @Felik  is there any other module which doesnot require installation of drupal commerce as it might slow down our website. Because we wont be using it for any other purpose

Comment: How are your prices stored? Are they a field attached to a node? If so how about using [`hook_node_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) to write any changes to a history table in a custom module? I suppose another option would be to turn on revisioning, and then just querying the revision table to fetch the price history.

Comment: its a field attached to the node. Can u plz elaborate on the process.

Comment: @user2129794 I've just found a new module that looks like a better option.